# Infinite loop with setState & onClick arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js 13 and fetching all genres from the movie database API into a server component and storing them in the **allGenres** variable:

```
import { fetchData } from "@/src/helpers/helpers";
import { MediaSingle } from "@/src/types/media";
import { apiKey } from "@/src/data/data";
import MediaGrid from "@/components/layout/grid/MediaGrid/MediaGrid";
import Container from "@/components/layout/container/Container";
import GenreSidebar from "@/components/layout/genre_sidebar/GenreSidebar";

const MoviesPage = async () => {
  const data = await fetchData(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1`);
  const movies: MediaSingle[] = await data.results;
  const genreData = await fetchData(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US`);
  const allGenres = await genreData.genres;
  return (
    <>
      <div className={"d-flex"}>
        <GenreSidebar genres={allGenres} />

        <Container>
          <h2 className='text-center'>
            <span className='title'>Genre Here</span>
          </h2>
          <MediaGrid media={movies} isShow={false} />
        </Container>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MoviesPage;
```

I then pass the **allGenres** array as a prop into the child component **GenreSidebar** which loops through each genre and outputs them as a list.

Each list item has an **onClick** which takes the name of the clicked genre (string) and updates the current genre via useState.

However once I click a list item once, the GenreSidebar renders infinitely.

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Genre } from "@/src/types/media";
import { apiKey } from "@/src/data/data";
import classes from "../genre_sidebar/GenreSidebar.module.css";

type GenreSidebarProps = {
  genres: Genre[];
};

const GenreSidebar = ({ genres }: GenreSidebarProps) => {
  const [currentGenre, setCurrentGenre] = useState<string>('');

  const genreClickHandler = (genre: string) => {

    setCurrentGenre(genre);

  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.sidebar}>
        <ul>
          {genres?.map((genre) => (
            <li onClick={() => genreClickHandler(genre.name)} key={genre.id}>
              {genre.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default GenreSidebar;
```

For what it's worth, here is my helper function code to make the fetch:

```
export const fetchData = async (url: string) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${url}`);
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Request Failed!");
    }
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you able to create a reproducible example of this that we can run for ourselbes (using something like codesandbox or stakcoverflow stack snippets)?

Comment: can you check network tabs if you are making infitiive fetch requests for `genreData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is with the click handler being created as a new object during the re-render, which then triggers another re-render. Try using `useCallback` hook and see if this fixes your issue. useCallback hook prevents unnecessary re-renders by memoizing the callback functions.

```
const genreClickHandler = useCallback((genre: string) =>{
  seCurrentGenre(genre);
}, []);
```

Comment: Ah yes that was it! I'm still a little confused because the function is dependent on a click. even when we click it for the first time, and that updates the state,  and triggers a re-render, why is it then a loop if the newly created function does not run until we click again?

Comment: It's not about "running" the function. The functions are properties of the component. When the component is re-rendered, it is resulting in "re-creating" (if you will) the click handler function. React sees it as a change in the component and triggers another re-render. useCallback prevents that by memoizing the handler function and thereby preventing the re-render.